# SignalR ASP.Net Core offers no way to Add Context Items via Typescript Client

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am Opening a Connection from my Typescript Client To My C# SignalR Hub. There seems no way to add Context Items.

Client:

```js
  public startConnection(hubRoute: string): void {
    const fixedRoute = `${this._baseUrl}${hubRoute}`;
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(fixedRoute)
      .build();

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));

/// where and how to add context items here?
  }
```

Server:

```cs
    public class EditorialHub: Hub<IEditorialHub>
    {
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            if (Context.Items["IssueNumber"] is string issueNumber)
            {
                await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "IssueNumber_" + issueNumber);

            }
            await  base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            if (Context.Items["IssueNumber"] is string issueNumber)
            {
                await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "IssueNumber_" + issueNumber);

            }
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

Ho can I add the "IssueNumber" Context.Item From the Client?

Comment: What is context here ? Where did you get that ?

Comment: Context is a property of the Baseclass Hub.

Comment: So you want client side send Context object to signalr ?

Comment: Correct. I can't find a way to fill Context.Items from the Client side.

Comment: I think signalr client cant do that because that is server side object

Comment: I thought it can also be set by the client and just roundtrips with every request. That's disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way, although couldn't find in documentation anywhere.
You can pass into the value any collection you want if that is a complex object(just specify the type where I put string value).

```cs
public void SetContextItems(string key, string value)
{
   Context.Items.Add(key, value);
}
```

This is for the server side*.
For the client side you can call this method pretty much the same way as @Tony Ngo did.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data from client to SignalR hub like this

```
    public async Task Send(string userId)
    {
        var message = $"Send message to you with user id {userId}";
        await Clients.Client(userId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

    public string GetConnectionId()
    {
        return Context.ConnectionId;
    }
```

I define 2 method 1 to send message from server to client name Send and 1 method to recieve message from client send to server

And in js code

```
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hub")
    .build();

connection.start().then(function () {
            console.log("connected");

            connection.invoke('getConnectionId')
                .then(function (connectionId) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('conectionId', connectionId);
                    // Send the connectionId to controller
                }).catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));;
        });

        $("#sendmessage").click(function () {
            var connectionId = sessionStorage.getItem('conectionId');
            connection.invoke("Send", connectionId);
        });

        connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        });
```

`connection.invoke('getConnectionId')` will be method to send data from client to server

and `connection.on("ReceiveMessage"` will be message to receive message send from client to server